# Wifi connected but no internet

Tags: debian, wifi

I've just install a Debian 12 on my Dell laptop 5470.
Everything went fine and I can access the internet through my ethernet cable.
I also configured the wifi connection in the advanced network config and everything is ok (I have the 4 bars icon saying the wifi connection is active).
However when I shift to my wireless connection I get the "No internet" message in my browser.
`sudo iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Livebox-9738"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: A0:39:EE:78:97:38   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:33   Missed beacon:0
```

I just can't figure out where this problem comes from.
Can someone help me ?
Note: I previously had an Ubuntu 22.04 installed on this laptop and the wifi worked just fine.

///// UPDATE ///////

`sudo ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:7b:eb:43:d9:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 74685sec preferred_lft 74685sec
    inet6 fe80::867b:ebff:fe43:d940/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:b3:18:36:8a:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.17/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 77471sec preferred_lft 77471sec
    inet6 fe80::4966:9713:1937:80ea/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`sudo ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 linkdown 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.17 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.20 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.17 metric 600
```

`ping -c3 1.1.1.1`

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2027ms
pipe 2
```

`ping -c3 bbc.co.uk`

```
ping: bbc.co.uk: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: With wireless, what does `ip addr show` give you? And `ip route`? What does `ping -c3 1.1.1.1` return, and what about `ping -c3 bbc.co.uk`? Please add these all to your question (as formatted text, not screenshots)

Comment: @roaima Here are the results (see the Update section in my post".

Comment: Please disconnect your ethernet and try the four commands again

Comment: @roaima I get the exact same result.

Comment: I need to see the results please. They still show your ethernet connected but unavailable

Comment: Sorry, disconnected but available

Comment: @roaima No pb and thanks for helping out. I finally found out the issue. See my post below.

Comment: `default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 linkdown ` prevents to access Internet using Wifi: it's the first used default route, using a disconnected Ethernet path. `From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable` 192.168.1.20  that's the IP set on the Ethernet NIC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I finally found out where the issue comes from.
It's not a software problem but a hardware problem due to the bios settings.
For those who have the same issue:

Reboot and press `F2` to enter the bios.

- Go to the `Power Management` section then click `Wireless Radio Control`
- Uncheck both the `Control WLAN Radio` and the `Control WWAN Radio` checkboxes
- Save the changes and reboot

I recently had a similar wifi issue with another Dell computer and it also turned out to be a bios setting issue.
I don't know why Dell features such obscure options as it takes hours if not days before figuring out the problem.
Anyway, I hope it helps.

Comment: See my comment about the additional default route using Ethernet. The issue wasn't about hardware. I guess your reboot "fixed" it.

Comment: @A.B I don't think so. I rebooted several times before modifying the bios and I still had the wifi issue.

Comment: Maybe you fixed a problem, but all the information you provided is bogus: it tells it didn't attempt to use the Wireless interface but did attempt to use the disconnected Ethernet interface. I'm just telling what your question tells.

Comment: What if the `Control WLAN Radio` and `Control WWAN Radio` options were responsible for the information I provided ?  
This is what `sudo ip route`now says after the bios changes:
`default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.17 metric 600
default dev enp0s31f6 scope link metric 1002 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.12.5 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000`
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.17 metric 600

Comment: It's not related to BIOS. Now your Ethernet default route metric went from 0 to 1002 (1002 > 600) (and also probably lost an address, which is probably related) so isn't selected as the actual default route. You made multiple changes and assume one of them did the trick, while most probably that's an other one. Maybe you just unplugged the cable and rebooted, preventing the interface to get an address. Then the problem would reappear the next time it's plugged. I can't know because there's no information to guess.